# Array Sort Adds Extra Key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

When using `natcasesort()` I am getting an extra array key at the end of my array.

With my example, I am creating an array of file names from a directory:

```
if (is_dir($files_path)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($files_path)) {
    while (($fileName = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      if (pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'yml') {
        $fileList[] = $fileName;
      }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}

$fileList[] = natcasesort($fileList);
```

This only happens when applying a sort to the array.

Also, if I write the last line as:

```
$sortedFileList[] = natcasesort($fileList);
```

`$sortedFileList` returns only the "*extra*" array key. So maybe there is a problem with my array structure? Should I just use `array_pop()`?

Why is `natcasesort()` or any `sort()` option, returning this value in this case?

Comment: `natcasesort` sorts in-place, and returns a boolean with the sorting success result.

Comment: `$sortedFileList[] = natcasesort($fileList);` using natcasesort, or sort, or ksort, rsort, or any of the sort **does not need** to be reassigned just like the answer below, just apply it on the array and it arranges it

Comment: See above; make `$fileList[] = natcasesort($fileList);` just `natcasesort($fileList);` and then your filelist should be sorted. See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php (Return type: bool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`natcasesort` does not return an *extra* key, it returns (as per the [documentation](https://php.net/natcasesort))

```
Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
```

So just sort it as `natcasesort($fileList);`

Comment: I guess my question maybe isn't as accurate now, the problem is that this array populates a list of checkboxes in a form and that boolean key shows in the list. I guess I will have to further manipulate the array before rendering the form element?